# Can't POST form data using FastAPI because "Form data requires "python-multipart" but it is installed

Tags: python, html, fastapi

**Overview:**
I'm building a simple FastAPI application with python and trying to grab form data from a simple HTML form. FastAPI leverages 'python-multipart' and installs it as a dependency along with FastAPI (see requirements.txt below) but when starting the app, I get an error stating that 'Form data requires "python-multipart" to be installed.' (see screenshot below).

**Troubleshooting**
So far, I have tried both uninstall and re-installing the package in multiple directories (both */root* and */app*) but to no avail and wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue or has additional insight?

Server.Py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

router = APIRouter()


app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")



@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request, image: str = Form(...), website: str = Form(...), text: str = Form(...), sentences: str = Form(...)):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/test")
def test(request: Request):
   print("*********", request)
   return "Check console"
```

Requirements.txt

```
anyio==3.5.0
asgiref==3.5.0
click==8.0.4
fastapi==0.75.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.13.0
idna==3.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pydantic==1.9.0
python-multipart==0.0.5
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.17.1
typing_extensions==4.1.1
uvicorn==0.17.6
```

Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Content Streamliner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/5.1.1/lux/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-mOju8pKJzu/lzzsmSWS8MrvFTXE9JMdOmhsz4OzN4NNfkERAUt4M7qjVQTbrWpx5SAJCv6Z2mrGY20ta6W2n+Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Content Streamliner</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Audio</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="image-search" class="form-label mt-4">Image Search:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" id="image-search">
        <label for="website" class="form-label mt-4">URL:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="website" id="url">
        <label for="text" class="form-label mt-4">Enter your text:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" id="text">
        <label for="sentences" class="form-label mt-4">Number of Sentences:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="sentences" id="sentences">
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
       </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: May not be related to your error, but you should add an encryption type to your form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Have you checked that you are running Uvicorn from the right virtual environment?

Comment: well I had the same issue and fixed it by just installing the module
>> pip install python-multipart